# Nesting webparts programatically

Tags: 2010, web-part, development, content

I have a user requirement to add a webpart inside another; I am creating a tabbed container webpart, inside which the user wishes to add other webparts. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

If you have your own webpart it may be possible but you have to do all the plumbing your self. The standard webpart framework does not provide any thing for nesting webparts.

Otherwise you could try using [Easy Tabs](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/07/26/easy-tabs-version-5-is-out/) to add tabs to SharePoint, these tabs allow (multiple) webparts.

Comment: EasyTabs would be the way to go

Comment: Unfortunately EasyTabs isn't appropriate as the client wants a very simple no coding option, and we have very complex requirements about the security / visibility of the tabs, one tab control must have tabs that are visible / hidden from many different group.